# Two representing measures and the closed support

Tags: integration, measure-theory

Suppose that we have $\varphi(f)=\int_Xfd\mu_1=\int_Xfd\mu_2$ for two measures $\mu_1,\mu_2$-here $X$ is some compact subset of the complex plane and $f$ is supposed to belong to so called *uniform algebra*, say $A$. I would like to avoid any detailed discussion what does it mean: I would say only that $A$ is a subalgebra of $C(X)$ (one can think for example of the algebra being the uniform closuer of polynomials). Let $X_1,X_2$ be the closed support of $\mu_1,\mu_2$. Is it true that $\varphi(f)=\int_{X_2}fd\mu_1$?

Comment: What if $X_{1},X_{2}$ are disjoint and form a partition of $X$?

Comment: Without further assumptions on $A $, thus will not work. For example,  if $A $ consists precisely of the constants,  then $\int f \,d\mu_1=\int f\,d\mu_2$ will hold for all $f \in A $ if and only if there total masses coincide, independent of their support.